# Picking up changed values of ASP textbox

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I'm trying to create a dynamic textbox that I can use to allow the entry of multiple values. I employed javascript for this purpose, thinking that this would allow me to grab the text value and place it in a list, before passing it to my web app. However, the code `document.getElementById('<%=sidemgr.ClientID%>').value` only picks up the initial value of sidemgr.txt from it's creation.

How do I get the updated value of this textbox? Do I have to use a javascript textbox?

**Here is the javascript I have**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnAdd").click(function () {
            var value = document.getElementById('<%=sidemgr.ClientID%>').value;
            var field = $("#field").val();
            var input = "<div id='listDiv' />";
            var newRow = "<tr><td>" + field + "</td><td>" + value + "</td></tr>";
            $('#controls').append(newRow);
        });
    });
</script>
```

**and the html**

```
    <div>
       <asp:TextBox ID="sidemgr" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <br />
<input id="btnAdd" type="url" value="Add" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnProcess" runat="server" Text="Process" OnClick="Process" />
<table id="controls" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="10">        
        </table>
    </div>
```

**C# code behind**

```
protected void Process(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var parameters = Request.Form["parameters"];
        if (parameters != null && parameters.Count() > 0)
        {                
            parameters.Split(',').ToList().
                ForEach(p =>
                {
                    Response.Write(p + "<br />");
                });
        }
    }
```

Note that some of this is from a solution I found on SO a while ago.

Comment: @Cal279 Good call, I noticed that myself but forgot to update the question. Having said that, where `value` should be, there is only `undefined`. I accept that `field` is undefined at present because I haven't used it yet, but surely `value` should hold the value of my textbox?

Comment: Can you try accessing it using JQuery to see if there is any difference? - e.g. $('#<%=sidemgr.ClientID%>').val(); - Just as a guess (there is no logic in my reasoning).

Comment: @Cal279 No joy. I did revert back to `value`, and now that I've changed to a div instead of a table I can see it. Unfortunately, I can't use a div because I need to pass these values to my c# backend.

Comment: Not sure I follow. Can you post your updated code? How are you getting these values in the table back to your server side?

Comment: @Cal279 I'm using `#controls` in the hope of being able to access them by using `Request.Form["parameters"]` in my code-behind. That just passes me a big long list of controls, that I have to split up to a list. Then, when I have them split, I can access their `Text` properties. In theory, anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a hiddenfield to hold the values you want in the server, the way you are doing server doesnt the value of Request.Form["parameters"]

```js
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#btnAdd").click(function () {
                    var value = document.getElementById('<%=sidemgr.ClientID%>').value;
                    var field = $("#field").val();
                    var input = "<div id='listDiv' />";
                    var newRow = "<tr><td>" + field + "</td><td>" + value + "</td></tr>";
                    $("#parameters").val($("#parameters").val()+value+",")
                    $('#controls').append(newRow);
                });
            });
```

```html
       <div>
           <asp:TextBox ID="sidemgr" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
           <input type="hidden" id="parameters" name="parameters"/>
           <br />
           <input id="btnAdd" type="url" value="Add" />
           <asp:Button ID="btnProcess" runat="server" Text="Process" OnClick="Process" />
           <table id="controls" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="10">        
            </table>
        </div>
```

With this hiddenfield the server will receive the Request.Form["parameters"] with something like "value1,value2,"

Or you coud use multiple hiddenfields with name like "parameters[]", insert in the table, and work with Request.Form["parameters"] as a list

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a shot and get back to you, probably tomorrow now.